# Fastest way to run a differential update on two collections of different types?

Tags: c#, performance, linq

I have two collections of different types, `TSource` and `TTarget` respectively.

The `TTarget` collection will be updated with the items found in the `TSource` collection, but since these changes include workflow triggers, I must know what was added, updated and removed.

What is the fastest way to run a difference on these collections, assuming a `Func<TSource, TTarget, bool> Equals` function? This equality function will usually compare one key field between the two objects but not always.

The only solution I could find was to be explicit about what they key is (i.e. not hide it inside `Equals()` and use `Intersect` and `HashSet`:

```
void Main()
{
    string[] target = new[] { "1", "2", "3", "4" }; // collection that will be updated
    int[] source = new[] { 0, 1, 2 }; // collection with the items for comparison and update

    // I've used simple types to reduce complexity

    Func<string, string> targetKeyFunc = t => t;
    Func<int, string> sourceKeyFunc = s => s.ToString();

    HashSet<string> keySet = new HashSet<string>(
        source.Select(sourceKeyFunc).Intersect(target.Select(targetKeyFunc)));

    foreach(var it in source)
        if(keySet.Contains(sourceKeyFunc(it)))
            Console.WriteLine("Updated: {0}", it);
        else
            Console.WriteLine("Added: {0}", it);

    foreach(var it in target)
        if(!keySet.Contains(targetKeyFunc(it)))
            Console.WriteLine("Removed: {0}", it);
}
```

This is a good implementation but binds me to using a key selector.
Is there a faster or as-fast alternative that allows the use of an `Equals()` func as described above?

Comment: what  you want is to find out what elements in source are not present in target so you can update target with those values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only have a `Func<TSource, TTarget, bool> Equals` function the only possible algorithm is to have two nested loops and compare each element with each other element. Performance is quadratic and quickly unacceptable.

Knowledge of the key restricts the kind of possible "comparer functions" to the intuitive notion of equality by key. This enables the use of hashing.

Therefore you need to base this on a `Func<TItem, TKey>` and use some kind of hashing (`HashSet`, `ToDictionary` or `ToLookup`).

In database terms what you want is a full outer join. I suggest you keep a `Dictionary<TKey, Tuple<List<TItem>, List<TItem>>` which contains the set of items from both sources for a given key. First you add all items from both sources to the dictionary, then you iterate over its values and see which keys have only items from one of the sources.

Comment: I was afraid you would say that. It's problematic because each `keyFunc()` call for one of the sources translates to a database hit and we're working with a document database (RavenDB) so joins not available.

Comment: Surely RavenDB can return multiple documents/keys at once. Calculate all keys at once in one batch call.

Comment: I've thought of that but because I'm processing a large XML file, my processors will process only one item at a time (each item will require the transformation required above), so doing something like that would require a big loop for processing them all at once :S. I'll start by enabling agressive caching and take it from there.